# getting laravel 478 error on page loading

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling

I am still new in using laravel. For the first project that I tried, the 404 page error that shows up is the 404 page provided in laravel. Laravel's 404 page

But for my second project, the 404 page is showing up the old 404 page. Old 404 page

I'm not sure what changes I did that led to it. Is there a way to know? How do I change it so that it will show the 404 page made by laravel?

Comment: which version's of laravel they use?!

Comment: is it 404 or 478 error ?

Answer (score 0):

To customize errors in laravel you can place your custom error pages inside `resources/views/errors` folder (ex 404.blade.php). [Custom HTTP Error Pages](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/errors#custom-http-error-pages)